# Formatting Array into Lat Lng Array for Google Map API Format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps

How to format this array:

```
array = ["37.772, -122.214", "-27.467, 153.027"]
```

into Lat/Lng for google map API that look like this:

```
flightPlanCoordinates = [
{lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
{lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}];
```

I'm trying this code:

```
let latLngArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const gData = new google.maps.LatLng(array[i][0], array[i][1]);
  latLngArray.push(gData);
}
```

but it resulting lat lng without value:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` and `split` methods.

```js
const array = ["37.772, -122.214", "-27.467, 153.027"];

const updated = array.map(item => {
  const [lat, lng] = item.split(", ").map(x => Number(x));
  return { lat, lng };
});

console.log(updated);
```

Comment: Beat you to it ;)

Comment: `item.split(",").map(Number);` is more elegant, but don't steal it ;)

Comment: most of the answer can give the formatted value i want, but this just matched my case very well...

Answer (score 2):

Using map, split and destructing

```js
const flightPlanCoordinates = ["37.772, -122.214", "-27.467, 153.027"]
  .map(coor => { 
    const [lat,lng] = coor.split(","); 
    return {lat:+lat,lng:+lng} 
  })

console.log(flightPlanCoordinates)

// OR mapping to number after splitting

const flightPlanCoordinates1 = ["37.772, -122.214", "-27.467, 153.027"]
  .map(coor => { 
    const [lat,lng] = coor.split(",").map(Number); 
    return {lat,lng} 
  })

console.log(flightPlanCoordinates1)
```

Comment: Downvoters may comment as to what is the problem with above working solution

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with `slice` could be:

```js
const array = ["37.772, -122.214", "-27.467, 153.027"];

let flightPlanCoordinates = array.map(coor => ({lat: +coor.slice(0, coor.indexOf(',')),
                                         lng: +coor.slice(coor.indexOf(',') +1)}));

console.log(flightPlanCoordinates)
```

Comment: Split is neater than slice, and you access the string twice

Comment: I agree! It's just for the sake of variant :)

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to point it out. I think the nicest version so far is my `.map(coor => { 
    const [lat,lng] = coor.split(",").map(Number); 
    return {lat,lng} 
  })`

Comment: You do not need the `, -1` by the way

Comment: Yes, that one is more elegant